# Why does Dataset.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified) return null?

Tags: c#, dataset

I would like to ask regarding C# .Net.

Why does my `_DataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)` return a null value?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace test_for_error
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SqlDataAdapter _DataAdapter;
        private DataSet _DataSet;
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=BEB7WILLOW\BEB7WILLOW; 
                                                   Database=Cost_Estimate_DB; 
                                                   Trusted_Connection=No; 
                                                   User ID=sa; 
                                                   password=s@password1");

            _DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select client_name from cost_estimate", cn);

            _DataSet = new DataSet();
            _DataAdapter.Fill(_DataSet, "cost_estimate");
            this.txtClient.DataBindings.Add("Text", _DataSet, "cost_estimate.client_name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _DataSet.AcceptChanges();
            DataSet DatasetChanges = _DataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [DataSet.AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx) before [DataSet.GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx), which is resetting the RowState so nothing appears to be modified.

> "The RowState property of each DataRow also changes; Added and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed."

Answer (score 0):

@Sean

I did what you said and it works. But I have another concern, every time I extract the subset using this code

```
if (_Ds.HasChanges())
{
   DataSet DsChanges = _Ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
}
```

when I checked the data in my new dataset DsChanges the data that is extracted was still the original data upon loading of form? It should be the changes that I made in _Ds. I ended up using stored procedure and it was not the elegant way of solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   DataSet DatasetChanges = _DataSet.GetChanges(); 
   _DataSet.AcceptChanges();         
}
```

Comment: you can put in 4 spaces for the first line too to make it a clear code block